# UITextField being treated as nil when it isn't

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a piece of code intended to allow a user to change which unit of weight they are using. If they've already entered a value it is automatically converted between kilograms and pounds. It is changed by tapping on a UISegmentedControl where segment 0 is kilogram and segment 1 is pound.

Changing the first time works perfectly regardless of if the user went from kilogram to pound or vice versa. However, upon attempting to make a second conversion the program immediately crashes claiming that the value in the text field containing weight is nil even though it clearly contains text.

Here is my code as of now:

```
@IBAction func unitChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if let text = weightInput.text, text.isEmpty {
        //Does nothing since there is no weight to change the unit of
    }
    else {
        let weight: Int? = Int(weightInput.text!)
        var weightDouble: Double = Double(weight!)
        
        if (weightTypeInput.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
            //The user is trying to change from pounds to kilograms
            weightDouble = weightDouble * 0.45359237
        }
        else {
            //The user is trying to change from kilograms to pounds
            weightDouble = weightDouble * 2.2046226218
        }
        weightInput.text = String(weightDouble)
    }
}
```

[Here is what the code looks like in practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDRls.png)

Finally here is the error message I get:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If I put a default value for weightDouble it is always used for all subsequent conversion attempts. Has anyone here encountered a similar issue? I attempted to search online but I couldn't find anything to help.

Comment: your textField connection problem

Comment: try to resolve these force unwrapped lines: **a.)** `let weight: Int? = Int(weightInput.text!)` and **b.)**
`var weightDouble: Double = Double(weight!)`, because those don't look good at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the text value of your TextField is nil? Since you're simply checking it in the first if in my opinion that would not be the case.

Int can't parse numbers with a floating-point in them. It returns nil when you do this. You might want to parse it into a Double first and then convert it to Int.

I think your code should be as follows:

```
@IBAction func unitChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    guard let text = weightInput.text, !text.isEmpty, var weightDouble = Double(text) else { return }
    
    if (weightTypeInput.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        //The user is trying to change from pounds to kilograms
        weightDouble = weightDouble * 0.45359237
    }
    else {
        //The user is trying to change from kilograms to pounds
        weightDouble = weightDouble * 2.2046226218
    }
    
    weightInput.text = String(Int(weightDouble))
}
```